# Ruby on rails - Creating a calculation form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to create a calculation form in Ruby similiar to the picture below

( it's a screenshot of the from that i created using HTML and Javascript codepen:

http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/pNELXM )

[image: a busy cat]

It's suppose to work like this

The budget part
U add a budget and it get's divided by the three input fields and the results below it.

The weightings part
You have nine inputs field and the value's you enter there get divide the results of the previous one

Then lastly the objectives part where you can add and remove 7 columns rows

It's pretty complicated, but i just finished the Micheal Hart tutorial and I'm not sure how to approach this.

I was thinking of creating one Model named Management

But would i then have to create all the value inputs in the module?

```
$ rails generate model Budget budget:text weighings:text objectives:text confrences:text prob:text  user:references
```

Or should i create separate models?

Because my Migrate looks like this and i'm not sure how the extra input value's would be saved

**Migrate**

```
    class CreateBudgets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :budgets do |t|
      t.text :budget
      t.text :weighings
      t.text :objectives
      t.text :confrences
      t.text :prob
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Also I was using a code to add columns in JavaScript ( u can see it in the code pen link)

I'm unassuming i can use JavaScript for the calculations and the results get saved once i press submit?

Comment: it's too broad of a question. But on the topic of arrays, it'll probably be easier to use a separate table than to store a list as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found was by using the same [JS](http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/pNELXM) used on the codepen example and adding [nested forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891371/ruby-on-rails-adding-conferences-to-users/47774738#47774738) to my app so I could dynamically add new fields to run the calculation

Below is part of the code:

**Management**

```
   class ManagmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

    def index
     @managments = current_user.managments
     @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
    end

    def show
      @microposts = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page])
      @managment = Managment.find_by(id: params[:id])
      if !@managment
        raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
      end
      @user = @managment.user
    end

    def new
      @user = User.new
      @managment = Managment.new
      @microposts = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def edit
      @managment = Managment.find(params[:id])
      @microposts = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def create
      @managment = current_user.managments.build(managment_params)
      if @managment.save
        flash[:success] = "Managment created!"
        redirect_to @managment
      else
        @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def update
      @managment = Managment.find(params[:id])
      if @managment.update(managment_params)
        redirect_to @managment
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @managment.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Managment deleted"
      redirect_to managments_path
    end

    private

    def managment_params
      params.require(:managment).permit( 
      :title,  :budget,
      :procent1, :procent2, :procent3, :procent4,
      :procent5, :procent6, :procent7,
      :procent8, :procent9, :procent10,
      :procent11, :procent12, :result1,
      :result2, :result3,
      :lowprocent1, :lowprocent2, :lowprocent3,
      :medprocent1, :medprocent2, :medprocent3,
      :highprocent1, :highprocent2, :highprocent3,

      objectives_attributes: [
      :id, :objectivesname1,
      :lowobjectives1, :medobjectives1,
      :highobjectives1, :lowobjectives1,
      :medobjectives1, :highobjectives1,
      :lowprocent1,:medprocent1,:highprocent1,
      :_destroy],

       continentals_attributes: [
      :id, :objectivesname2,
      :lowobjectives2, :medobjectives2,
      :highobjectives2, :lowobjectives2, 
      :medobjectives2, :highobjectives2,
      :lowprocent2,:medprocent2,:highprocent2,
      :_destroy],

       internationals_attributes: [
      :id, :objectivesname3,
      :lowobjectives3, :medobjectives3,
      :highobjectives3, :lowobjectives3,
      :medobjectives3, :highobjectives3,
      :lowprocent3,:medprocent3,:highprocent3,
      :_destroy])
    end

    def correct_user
      @managment = current_user.managments.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to managments_path if @managment.nil?
    end

end
```

**_managment.html.rb**

```
 <div class="field" id="weighings">
    <div class="colum">
    <h4>Low presence</h4>
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="lowplow" onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.procent4 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="lowpmed" onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.procent5 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="lowphigh" onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.procent6 %>">%
    </div>

    <div class="colum">
    <h4>Medium presence</h4>
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="medplow"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.procent7 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="medpmed"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.procent8 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="medphigh"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.procent9 %>">%
    </div>

    <div class="colum">
    <h4>High presence</h4>
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="highplow"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.procent10 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="highpmed"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.procent11 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="highphigh"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.procent12 %>">%
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
      <h1>Objectives</h1>

    <h4>low presence</h4>
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="objectiveinput" onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.objectivesname1 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.lowprocent1 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.medprocent1 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.highprocent1 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.lowobjectives1 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.medobjectives1 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.highobjectives1 %>">

    <h4>Medium presence</h4>
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="objectiveinput"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.objectivesname2 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.lowprocent2 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.medprocent2 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.highprocent2 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.lowobjectives2 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.medobjectives2 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.highobjectives2 %>">

    <h4>High presence</h4>
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="objectiveinput"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.objectivesname3 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.lowprocent3 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.medprocent3 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.highprocent3 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.lowobjectives3 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.medobjectives3 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= managment.highobjectives3 %>">

  </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Data</h3>
            <!--START BUDGET FORM -->
      <form class="budgetresultsoutput" id="totalbudget">
        <!--End budget output-->

        <!--Procentages output-->
        <div class="row datarowbudget">
          <div class="colum" id="columtext">
            <p>P.O.I</p>
            <input class="box names" type="text" id="title3-0" value="Domestic" onkeydown="return false" placeholder="Slice #1 title" />
            <input class="box names" type="text" id="title2-1" value="Continental" onkeydown="return false" placeholder="Slice #1 title" />
            <input class="box names" type="text" id="title2-2" value="International" onkeydown="return false" placeholder="Slice #1 title" />
            <input class="box" type="text" id="title2-2" value="Total" onkeydown="return false" placeholder="Slice #1 title" />
          </div>

          <!-- COLUM 1/LOW-->
          <div class="colum" id="regio">
            <p>Low</p>
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-0" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-1" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-2" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-9" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
          </div>
          <!-- COLUM 2 MEDIUM -->
          <div class="colum" id="regio">
            <p>Medium</p>
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-3" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-4" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-5" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-10" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
          </div>
          <!-- COLUM 3 HIGH -->
          <div class="colum" id="regio">
            <p>High</p>
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-6" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-7" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-8" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
            <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-11" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
          </div>
          <!--Budget output-->
          <div class="colum columbudget" id="regio">
            <p>Budget</p>
            <input id="budgetdata" type="text" name="budget" value="<%= managment.budget %>" onkeydown="return false"><br>
          </div>
          <div class="colum" id="regioprec">
            <!--Low presence:-->
            <p>Procentages</p>
            <input class="procentages" id="lowdata" type="text" name="low" value="<%= managment.procent1 %>" onkeydown="return false">%<br>
            <input class="procentages"id="meddata" type="text" name="low" value="<%= managment.procent2 %>" onkeydown="return false">%<br>
            <input class="procentages" id="highdata" type="text" name="low" value="<%= managment.procent3 %>" onkeydown="return false">%<br>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--End procentages input-->
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Desired return sheet</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Expected return sheet</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
        <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Cost sheet</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <span class="timestamp">

    <% if current_user?(managment.user) %>
      <%= link_to "delete", managment, method: :delete,
                                       data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</li>


<script type="text/javascript">
//CALCULATE MANAGEMENT
function calculateManagement() {

  //START OF BUDGET(data) PART
  var domesticResultLow = document.getElementById('value3-0');
  var domesticResultMed = document.getElementById('value3-1');
  var domesticResultHigh = document.getElementById('value3-2');
  var domesticResultFinal = document.getElementById('value3-9');

  var continentalResultLow = document.getElementById('value3-3');
  var continentalResultMed = document.getElementById('value3-4');
  var continentalResultHigh = document.getElementById('value3-5');
  var continentalResultFinal = document.getElementById('value3-10');

  var globalResultLow = document.getElementById('value3-6');
  var globalResultMed = document.getElementById('value3-7');
  var globalResultHigh = document.getElementById('value3-8');
  var globalResultFinal = document.getElementById('value3-11');

  var lowProcentageLow = document.getElementById('lowplow').value;
  var lowProcentageMed = document.getElementById('lowpmed').value;
  var lowProcentageHigh = document.getElementById('lowphigh').value;

  var medProcentageLow = document.getElementById('medplow').value;
  var medProcentageMed = document.getElementById('medpmed').value;
  var medProcentageHigh = document.getElementById('medphigh').value;

  var highProcentageLow = document.getElementById('highplow').value;
  var highProcentageMed = document.getElementById('highpmed').value;
  var highProcentageHigh = document.getElementById('highphigh').value;

  var resultOne = document.getElementById('result1').value;
  var resultTwo = document.getElementById('result2').value;
  var resultThree = document.getElementById('result3').value;

  var lowProcentLow = (resultOne /100 )* lowProcentageLow;
  domesticResultLow.value = lowProcentLow;

    var lowProcentMed = (resultOne /100 )* lowProcentageMed;
  domesticResultMed.value = lowProcentMed;

  var lowProcentHigh = (resultOne /100 )* lowProcentageHigh;
  domesticResultHigh.value = lowProcentHigh;


  var medProcentLow = (resultTwo /100 )* medProcentageLow;
  continentalResultLow.value = medProcentLow;

  var medProcentMed = (resultTwo /100 )* medProcentageMed;
  continentalResultMed.value = medProcentMed;

  var medProcentHigh = (resultTwo /100 )* medProcentageHigh;
  continentalResultHigh.value = medProcentHigh;


  var highProcentLow = (resultThree /100 )* highProcentageLow;
  globalResultLow.value = highProcentLow;

  var highProcentMed = (resultThree /100 )* highProcentageMed;
  globalResultMed.value = highProcentMed;

  var highProcentHigh = (resultThree /100 )* highProcentageHigh;
  globalResultHigh.value = highProcentHigh;

  domesticResultFinal.value = resultOne;
  continentalResultFinal.value = resultTwo;
  globalResultFinal.value = resultThree;

  //END OF BUDGET(data) PART

}


//No letters
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
//
</script>
```