# Ruby on Rails || Adding conferences to users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an app where u can see all conferences in the world.

What I've got:

- creating an conference
- showing all conferences

Now what I want to create is an button that let's me add a conference to a user.

What do I want to accomplish with this:

- adding conference to users
- showing added conferences in a list
- viewing conferences and adding content

I was thinking of an button that copies the attributes of selected object and adds it to an selected user for future manipulation and viewing of the conference

I'm asking if someone can tell me how to accomplish this

https://consulegem-salman15.c9users.io/conferences

**Migration conferences**

```
class CreateConferences < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :conferences do |t|

      t.string :conference 
      t.string :country 
      t.string :month 
      t.string :presence 
      t.string :audience 
      t.integer :cost 
      t.text :content

      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :conferences, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

**Controller conference**

```
class ConferencesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy
    def index

      @conferences = Conference.paginate(page: params[:page])

      if params[:search]
        @conferences = Conference.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
      else
        @conferences = Conference.all.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
      end
    end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @conference = Conference.new
  end

  def create

    @conference = current_user.conferences.build(conference_params)
    if @conference.save
      flash[:success] = "conference created!"
      redirect_to conferences_path
    else
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @conference.destroy
    flash[:success] = "conference deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end


  private

    def conference_params
      params.require(:conference).permit(:conference,:country , :month, :presence, :audience, :cost ,:picture)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

    def correct_user
      @conference = current_user.conferences.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @conference.nil?
    end

end
```

**Model controller**

```
class Conference < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to:user
      default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
      mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
      validates :user_id, presence: true
      validates :conference, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
      validate  :picture_size
      scope :conference, -> (conference) { where conference: conference }

      def self.search(search)
        where("conference LIKE ? OR country LIKE ? OR month LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")

      end


      private

        # Validates the size of an uploaded picture.
        def picture_size
          if picture.size > 5.megabytes
            errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5MB")
          end
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found was by adding a SubscriptionsController that is nested in the `ConferenceController` and a `RelationshipController`

**SubscriptionController**

```
    class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_conference, only: :create

    def index
     @subscriptions = current_user.subscriptions
     @subscriptions = Subscription.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

  def show
    @subscription = Subscription.find_by(id: params[:id])

  end 

  def create
    if current_user.subscriptions.create(conference: @conference)
      flash[:success] = "You are now subscribed to { @conference.conference }"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Could not create subscription."
    end
    redirect_to conferences_path
  end

  def destroy
    @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.find(params[:id])
    if @subscription.destroy
      flash[:success] = "You are no longer subscribed to { @conference.conference }"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Oh noes"
    end

    redirect_to conferences_path
  end

  def set_conference
    @conference = Conference.find_by id: params["conference_id"]
  end
end
```

**RelationshipController**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user

  def create
    @conference = Conference.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(@conference)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @conference }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**ConferenceController**

```
class ConferencesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

    def index
      @conferences = Conference.paginate(page: params[:page])


      if params[:search]
        @conferences = Conference.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
      else
        @conferences = Conference.all.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
      end
    end

    def show

      @conference = Conference.find(params[:id])

    end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @conference = Conference.new
  end

  def create

    @conference = Conference.new(conference_params)
    @conference.user = current_user
    if @conference.save
      flash[:success] = "conference created!"
      redirect_to conferences_path
    else
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @conference.destroy
    flash[:success] = "conference deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end


  private

    def conference_params
      params.require(:conference).permit(:conference,:country , :month, :presence, :audience, :cost ,:picture)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

    def correct_user
      @conference = current_user.conferences.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @conference.nil?
    end

end
```